# Is calling Task.Yield() in OnInitializedAsync() a safe way to get @ref= variables populated?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

This question is about Blazor server. As @HH comments below, the whole Yield() approach doesn't make sense for wasm.

At present, the way to get any `@ref=` variable declared in a component reference in the razor page populated is to call `Task.Yield()` in `OnInitializedAsync()`. When it returns from the Yield(), all of the @ref variables are now set. So as of today, this works.

One experienced Blazor developer I respect says this is supported and will work going forward and as such, can be depended on. A second experienced Blazor developer I also respect a lot says this is just how Blazor works today, it may not work tomorrow, and all code needed to reference an @ref should go in `OnAfterRenderAsync()`.

So my question is, can I depend on calling `Task.Yield()` in `OnInitializedAsync()` to populate all `@ref` variables? Or should I move that code to `OnAfterRenderAsync()`? I figure if that stops working there's going to be a lot of Blazor apps breaking. But breaking changes like that happen and best as I can find, there is no promise that `Task.Yield()` will accomplish anything.

[Also asked in the aspnetcore discussion forum (no replies so far).](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/50819)

Comment: Yield() is unlikely to work in Blazor Wasm.

Comment: @HH that makes sense. But I'm Blazor server - I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yield() and Delay(1) are hacks.

You will usually get a Render but I don't think it is guaranteed. Depends too much on the scheduler and on what other async activity is going on.

Only in OnAfterRender() can you be sure that they are set.